# Distributing an application written in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, jruby, compiled

We have an existing web application that is written in Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.x.
Our original model was software as a service but in investigating in our industry there are times where hosting our code on the client may be a better option for privacy reasons (having the clients data stored at their own data center).

What are the best measures to protect our codebase from being viewed?  Has anyone had experience compiling into JRuby or similar solutions.  What are the steps are caveats?

Thanks

Comment: We're not using any ruby VM at the moment. I'm looking for a solution that will help us hide the ruby cody and still provide an easy way for the client to install and run our application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [warbler](https://github.com/nicksieger/warbler). You can package your rails app as a standalone, compiled (i.e., java classes) java app for distribution if you use the 'executable' and 'compiled' features, you can get compiled java classes packaged into a servlet container that can run as `'java -jar app.jar'`.